# How to upload a table and run sql on it?

Tags: sql

I want to practice some SQL locally on specific tables that I have.
What I need is simply to take a table, upload it to a software I can run SQL on and work with it. nothing more. no servers, no other users.
I tried a few different products but just can't find one that allows this option without creating a server and setting up connections.
Please help :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like **SQLite** would work well for your purpose. SQLite is **serverless**

You can then use a shell or DOS prompt to create a db for it, create your table(s) for the db, and then upload your data to the table(s).

https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

**sql fiddle**, maybe this is what are you looking for.